# How do I reference net40 framework assembly from .NetStandard class library?

Tags: c#, .net, csproj, .net-standard, project.json

Under the project.json project system I was able to specify framework assembly dependencies per framework. The [dotnet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/libraries) (now out of date) show the below example.

```
{
    "frameworks":{
        "net20":{
            "frameworkAssemblies":{
                "System.Net":""
            }
        },
        "net35":{
            "frameworkAssemblies":{
                "System.Net":""
            }
        },
        "net40":{
            "frameworkAssemblies":{
                "System.Net":""
            }
        },
        "net45":{
            "frameworkAssemblies":{
                "System.Net.Http":"",
                "System.Threading.Tasks":""
            }
        },
        ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259": {
            "buildOptions": {
                "define": [ "PORTABLE" ]
             },
             "frameworkAssemblies":{
                 "mscorlib":"",
                 "System":"",
                 "System.Core":"",
                 "System.Net.Http":""
             }
        },
        "netstandard16":{
            "dependencies":{
                "NETStandard.Library":"1.6.0",
                "System.Net.Http":"4.0.1",
                "System.Threading.Tasks":"4.0.11"
            }
        },
    }
}
```

How do I do this under csproj for the updated dotnet sdk v1.1.1? I want to reference System.Configuration for net40, but not for netstandard 1.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Pankaj - I went with a modified version of your suggestion. The key is just using the Reference element.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net40</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Common.Logging" Version="3.4.0-Beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.0.0-beta06" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'">
    <PackageReference Include="Common.Logging" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Common.Logging.NLog40" Version="3.3.0" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Console\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: FWIW, the `Condition` attribute can be applied to `Reference` as well; so, if you share most of the references, but just have one or two that are unique, you don't have to repeat the entire `ItemGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow below mentioned steps:

1. In Visual Studio right click project and select unload.
2. Again right click and edit project.
3. Change "TargetFramework" value to required .Net Framework version. e.g. Following example sets target framework version to 4.5.2

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
4. Reload project.
5. Add reference of System.Configuration assembly.
6. Unload and edit project again.
7. Edit System.Configuration reference as follows.

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="System.Configuration" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net452'" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   There may be easy way out which I am not aware of but above method should work.

Comment: You don't need to unload a project to edit it in VS2017.